# Can't open chromedriver on linux

Tags: linux, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to run selenium test on linux, but cannot open the chromedriver. I put the chromedriver in `/user/local/bin` ,then I exec `./chromedriver` and show this error.

```
[root@VM_0_11_centos bin]# ./chromedriver 
Starting ChromeDriver 2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.


[1531710919.966][SEVERE]: bind() returned an error, errno=99
```

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text

Comment: @Marged oh,I'm sorry. Already edited.

Comment: @Sven Why is `selenium` tagged in `./chromedriver`? Am I missing something?

Comment: @DebanjanB Sorry, Maybe it is not very clearly. I want to use selenium to simulate  login action. It's OK in macOS but failed in linux. And this error occurred.